# Why am I getting PayPal::SDK::Core::Exceptions::MethodNotAllowed?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

I keep running into the following error despite following the [implementation guide](https://devtools-paypal.com/guide/pay_paypal/ruby?interactive=OFF&env=sandbox) to the letter:

```
PayPal::SDK::Core::Exceptions::MethodNotAllowed in SiteController#execute_payment
Failed. Response code = 405. Response message = Method Not Allowed.
```

This is the offending line:

```
@payment.execute( :payer_id => params[:PayerID] )
```

What am I doing wrong? (here's my controller):

```
class SiteController < ApplicationController
    def index
    end

    def create_payment
        payment = PayPal::SDK::REST::Payment.new({
            :intent => "sale",
            :payer => {
                :payment_method => "paypal" },
                :redirect_urls => {
                :return_url => execute_payment_url,
                :cancel_url => "https://devtools-paypal.com/guide/pay_paypal/ruby?cancel=true" },
                :transactions => [ {
                    :amount => {
                    :total => "12",
                    :currency => "USD" },
                    :description => "creating a payment" } ] } )

        payment.transactions[0].item_list.items[0] = {
                quantity: 1,
                name: 'Poop',
                price: 12,
                currency: 'USD'
            }

        if payment.create
            session[:payment_id] = payment.id
            redirect_to payment.links[1].href
        end
    end

    def execute_payment
        @payment = PayPal::SDK::REST::Payment.new({
            :payment_id => session[:payment_id]})
        @payment.execute( :payer_id => params[:PayerID] )
    end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating a new payment you should use find.. Change:

```
    @payment = PayPal::SDK::REST::Payment.new({
        :payment_id => session[:payment_id]})
```

to

```
    @payment = PayPal::SDK::REST::Payment.find(session[:payment_id])
```

This resolved the issue in my copy of your code.